# Minimum stake threshold of 6000 XTZ

Tags: baking, solo-baking, staking, staking-balance, validation

What technical roadblocks exist that prevent the lowering of the 6000 XTZ baking eligibility threshold?

Lots of NFT artists and tech hobbyists over the past few years have expressed an interest in personally validating, in some small way, but lacking the minimum stake required to do so.

I wonder what technical limitations we're working with that will enable more bakers to get involved—personally, at a smaller stake—while keeping the protocol p2p efficient and safe to minimal stake DoS attacks.

Comment: Here's a poll to keep track of the community sentiment side of this question: https://twitter.com/BakingBenjamins/status/1762153570940371320

Answer (score 0):

Main issue is that it would lower the slashable amount per attestations, and we are limited in the amount of attestations we can reasonably propagate over the network and add in a block.

Moving to BLS sigs only would be a step in the right direction, but it's not something that can happen overnight given the infrastructure that depends on other keys.

Comment: Makes sense. At least we have the 600 tez + 5400 tez in delegations (and soon in others' stake) method to get small validators.  These people more often than not stay involved in the daily developments of the ecosystem and tend to contribute back.